# Extracting Transfer learning output from CNN Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

How to take the intermediate Transfer learning output. ? Eg:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
# ... Other Imports..

from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
model = Sequential()
resnet = ResNet50(include_top = False, pooling = 'avg', weights = 'imagenet')
model.add(resnet)
model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))
model.layers[0].trainable = False
```

Tried:

```
layer_output=model.get_layer('resnet').output
layer_output=model.get_layer('resnet').output
intermediate_model=tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=layer_output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unresolved [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42017) in Tensorflow on this problem. According to the issue, you need to pass inputs of both outer model and inner model to get the output of inner model.

```py
import numpy as np

layer_output = model.get_layer("resnet50").output
intermediate_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[model.input, resnet.input], outputs=[layer_output])

input_data = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 3)
result = intermediate_model.predict([input_data, input_data])

print(result[0].shape)
```

```
(7, 7, 2048)
```